# hover working properly with one class and not with another

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="channellist"></div>
```

Using Ajax i am getting the channels dynamically when the page loads and appending in the channellist container. After appending my html looks like this.

```
<div class="channellist" id="channellist">
   <div class="c01" id="c1"></div>
   <div class="c01" id="c2"></div>
   <div class="c01" id="c3"></div>
</div>
```

I tried like this

```
$('.channellist').hover(function() {
 alert(this.id);
});
```

I got the alert message.

when i tried the hover on c01 class i didnt got the alert.

```
$('.c01').hover(function() {
 alert(this.id);
});
```

I dont know where it is going wrong. Can anyone help to figure it out.

Comment: use event delegation see here http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since code is dynamically attached to the div, onload of the document the event will not be present, So use .live event or use .on by delegating the event. Then event will execute. For your reference Check this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/HimeshS/ocxoy6c2/

```
https://jsfiddle.net/HimeshS/ocxoy6c2/
```

For .live:

```
$(.c01).live("mouseenter", function(){
      alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: if people are using old version, they can use .live option.

Answer (score 3):

You need use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), try this

```js
$('.channellist').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.c01', function() {
 console.log(this.id);
});

// only for example 
setTimeout(function () {
  $('.channellist').html(
    '<div class="c01" id="c1">1</div>' +
    '<div class="c01" id="c2">2</div>' + 
    '<div class="c01" id="c3">3</div>'
  );
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="channellist" id="channellist"></div>
```

[$.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> The name "hover" used as a shorthand for the string "mouseenter
>   mouseleave". It attaches a single event handler for those two events,
>   and the handler must examine event.type to determine whether the event
>   is mouseenter or mouseleave. Do not confuse the "hover"
>   pseudo-event-name with the .hover() method, which accepts one or two
>   functions.

Answer (score 2):

*Using Ajax i am getting the channels dynamically*

This can be sorted using event delegation like:

```
$('#channellist').on('mouseenter', '.c01', function() {
     alert(this.id);
});
```

syntax of event delegation is something like:

```
$(staticParent).on(event, selector, callback);
```

where `$(staticParent)` should be the element which was available when DOM was ready, In your case it seems to be `#channellist` element.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="channellist" id="channellist">
   <div class="c01" id="c1"></div>
   <div class="c01" id="c2"></div>
   <div class="c01" id="c3"></div>
</div>
```

Your blocks are empty, their height is 0, and you can't hover on tham.
Try to make height more, or print some text inside,

Like:

```
<div class="channellist" id="channellist">
   <div class="c01" id="c1">1</div>
   <div class="c01" id="c2">2</div>
   <div class="c01" id="c3">3</div>
</div>
```